# while getting image src using jquery returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var aa = $('.page-1 img').attr('src');
  alert(aa);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="dddddd.jpg" width="76" height="100" class="page-1" />
</body>

</html>
```

while getting image scr using jquery returns undefined can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: Your selector `$('.page-1 img')` might be invalid.

Comment: `.page-1 img` means an `img` element *within* an element who has the `page-1` class.

Comment: Also, since you are using `class` and `tag` for selecting, multiple elements may be selected if they match the criteria. Using an `id` instead will be more appropriate if you are looking unique results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector should be `img.page-1`.

`.page-1 img` will try to find `img` tag inside an element with class `.page-1`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var aa = $('img.page-1').attr('src');
  alert(aa);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://placebear.com/g/200/300" width="76" height="100" class="page-1" />
```

Comment: Added a linkable img so running your snippet doesn't look as if it's broken.

Answer (score 0):

You are using selector in wrong way. That's why script is return error. Since `.page-1` is on the same element you need select it by following pattern.

`$('img.page-1').attr('src');`

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var aa= $('img.page-1').attr('src');
  alert(aa);
});
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://www.google.ae/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png" width="76" height="100" class="page-1" />
</body>
</html>
```

`.page-1 img` this method will find the child `img` element of `.page-1`. Since it is not and there is no child element so selector won't work.